# Are there any differences between "appearances at" and "appearances on"?

Tags: prepositions

We say:

> Her appearance **on** "Friends" was just amazing.

and I think we also say:

> His appearance **at** 84th Annual Academy Awards was somewhat surprising.

So, are there any differences with these sentences? Is it exchangeable, or is there any rule to use proper prepositions in each situation?

Answer (score 1):

> **On**

On TV (on the radio etc.)

"Friends" is a TV show, so "on 'Friends'"

> **At**

At an event

The 84th Annual Academy Awards is an event, so "at the 84th Annual Academy Awards"